# Reopen vote review badges are difficult to achieve

Tags: feature-request, badges, review, review-badges

[Review] and [Steward] badges are incredibly difficult to achieve on SO for "Reopen Votes". Right now, there have been 8176 reopen vote reviews. It will take *years* for individuals to achieve the gold "Steward" badge.

I propose the thresholds be reduced for reopen vote reviews.

Comment: If you're doing this solely to get a badge please stop reviewing. You should be reviewing to help you the community, not to get a few more bytes next to your name.

Comment: Not difficult. Reviewing is quite easy. But you need to use common sense and have a bit of patience.

Comment: Oh no, some pixels are difficult to obtain. *The horror!*

Comment: In all seriousness, I agree with @Ben; don't review for badges. Review if you care about cleaning up SO community stuff.

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions here about WHY I want the badge and HOW I go about getting it. My point is simply that it's much easier to earn the other gold review badges. I think they should all be equally easy/difficult to earn.

Comment: @flem If you updated your question to be about making the other gold review badges as hard to get as the re-open one, I'm sure you'll get a ton of upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree the Silver and Gold badges, even review badges are something to work towards.

Directly from the badge description page:

> Gold Badges are rare. You’ll have to actively work toward these.
> They’re something of an accomplishment!
>
> Silver badges are awarded for longer term goals. Silver badges are
> uncommon, but definitely attainable if you’re interested.

We should not be able to get any of the badges easily even the review badges.  I think the thresholds should remain the same for all of the review queues.

If it takes years to get the badge, then all you are doing is spending time improving the community which is really the point.  You shouldn't be reviewing just to get the badges.

Comment: I said nothing about making it easy. I'm asking that it be equally easy/difficult to earn any review badge of a given class. Right now it's near impossible to earn gold "Reopen" but gold "Close Votes" can be earned in a minimum of 25 days.

Comment: @flem It might be hard, but it's not impossible. The silver Beta badge is impossible.

Comment: @YannisRizos "near impossible" were my words.